# modifying ng-grid checkboxes with custom css, modifying space

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm bad with CSS, and so far no luck. For some reason, the CSS style won't apply to `.ngSelectionCheckbox` and `.ngSelectionHeader`.

I'm trying to use the CSS from csscheckbox.com, changed the class name from the readme to mine and no luck.

This is my current table:
[image]

This is what i need it to look like:
[image]

Also, I have no idea how to make the bottom of the row push up, and align the checkboxes appropriately with the numbers.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are those rows static html or are you using ng-repeat with some sort of data provider?

Comment: ng-repeat, data provider in the back end done with ajax

Comment: mkay..just makin a fiddle to work with

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while I am not going to style the whole thing for you, the functionality of checking the box is like so

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>CPT CODE/Service Provider;</th>
            <th>Average Cost</th>
            <th>Offered Price</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-class="{'selected': row$index}">
              <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row$index" /></td>
              <td>{{row.code}}</td>
              <td>{{row.cost}}</td>
              <td>{{row.price}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp",[]);

app.controller("TestController", function($scope)
{
    $scope.data = [
        {
            "code":"a",
            "cost": 11,
            "price": 10
        },
        {
            "code":"b",
            "cost": 21,
            "price": 20
        },
        {
            "code":"c",
            "cost": 31,
            "price": 30
        }
    ];
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/25NVD/

The jist of it is, use `ng-repeat` to make the rows, use `ng-class` to assign the 'selected' class when `row$index` is checked. `$index` is the count created by `ng-repeat` which I used to make a unique model.